# Postgres query on nested JSONB field

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Hey I have a table with a JSONB field. I want to run a query (table scan), which find all records where a nested element lifecycle.time is equal to "100". I `"lifecycle:{time:"100"}`

Looking at documentation like this https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/how-to-query-a-postgres-jsonb-column-1433 shows no example of querying on a JSONB fild.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided much details, but as far as I can tell, you want something like this:

```
select *
from the_table
where the_column -> 'lifecycle' ->> 'time' = '100'
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
select *
from the_table
where the_column @> '{"lifecycle": {"time": "100"}}';
```

Comment: Thanks so much. i guess a follow up question - what if my nested elements was "lifecycle:{time:"100", steps: [{id:1}, {id"2]} and I wanted to find all records where lifecycle.steps contained an element with an id of 2?